# Select en bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap

Intento incluir un campo dentro de un formulario con la clase selectpicker de bootstrap pero el estilo no se agrega el estilo ni la búsqueda en vivo, alguna  idea de ¿por qué?  este es mi código

Estas son las librerías que uso, solo jquery la tengo de forma remota bootstrap lo tengo de forma local

```
    <link href="style/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="style/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Este es el formulario

```
   <div class="form-group">
   <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Nombre</label>
   <input type="email" class="form-control" name="nombre" placeholder="Email">
   </div>

   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Apellidos</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" name="nombre" placeholder="Email">
   </div>

    <div class="form-group">                                        
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Area</label><br/>
      <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
      <option data-tokens="ketchup mustard">Hot Dog, Fries and a Soda</option>
      <option data-tokens="mustard">Burger, Shake and a Smile</option>
      <option data-tokens="frosting">Sugar, Spice and all things nice</option>
      </select>                                          
     </div>

     <div class="form-group">
         <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Corrre electronico</label>
         <input type="email" class="form-control" name="apellidos" placeholder="Email">
     </div>


      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
           <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
          <input type="hidden"  name="tipo" value="1">                                                                                                                    
      </div>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Cancelar</button>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Registrarme</button>
</form><!-- Cierrra form registro -->
```

Comment: Ya has añadido las referencias de las librerías a tu HTML??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si dices que no se muestra correctamente el selectpicker de bootstrap es por que no has añadido las referencias de la librería te dejo tu mismo código pero con las referencias de la librería.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<form action="Registro" method="post"><!-- registro -->

   <div class="form-group">
   <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Nombre</label>
   <input type="email" class="form-control" name="nombre" placeholder="Email">
   </div>

   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Apellidos</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" name="nombre" placeholder="Email">
   </div>

    <div class="form-group">                                        
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Area</label><br/>
      <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
      <option data-tokens="ketchup mustard">Hot Dog, Fries and a Soda</option>
      <option data-tokens="mustard">Burger, Shake and a Smile</option>
      <option data-tokens="frosting">Sugar, Spice and all things nice</option>
      </select>                                          
     </div>

     <div class="form-group">
         <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Corrre electronico</label>
         <input type="email" class="form-control" name="apellidos" placeholder="Email">
     </div>


      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
           <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
          <input type="hidden"  name="tipo" value="1">                                                                                                                    
      </div>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Cancelar</button>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Registrarme</button>
</form><!-- Cierrra form registro -->
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Juan funciona perfecto

Answer (score 0):

Te falta agregar las librerias, en la [documentacion](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) muestran los enlaces externos par que funcione correctamente.

Estos serian los enlaces que necesitas:

**CSS**

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

**JS**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
```

aqui muestro tu código con el select funcionando:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<form action="Registro" method="post"><!-- registro -->

   <div class="form-group">
   <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Nombre</label>
   <input type="email" class="form-control" name="nombre" placeholder="Email">
   </div>

   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Apellidos</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" name="nombre" placeholder="Email">
   </div>

    <div class="form-group">                                        
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Area</label><br/>
     <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
      <option data-tokens="ketchup mustard">Hot Dog, Fries and a Soda</option>
      <option data-tokens="mustard">Burger, Shake and a Smile</option>
      <option data-tokens="frosting">Sugar, Spice and all things nice</option>
    </select>
                                         
     </div>

     <div class="form-group">
         <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Corrre electronico</label>
         <input type="email" class="form-control" name="apellidos" placeholder="Email">
     </div>


      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
           <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
          <input type="hidden"  name="tipo" value="1">                                                                                                                    
      </div>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Cancelar</button>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Registrarme</button>
</form><!-- Cierrra form registro -->
```

Te recomiendo que pruebes con el [Select2](https://select2.github.io/) el cual a mi parecer es un poco mas completo en algunos aspectos y se utiliza de la misma manera, espero te sirva

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda Alan  =)